Regular Expression matching double and single quotes in Dart
I want to strip a string off all sorts of symbols. Therefore I'm using a Regular Expression looking like this:
const kCleanWordRegex = r"[.,;!?：？。，()]+";

used like so:
sometext.replaceAll(kCleanWordRegex, '');

It works fine so far, but I figured I also need to strip the text of double quotes " and I cannot wrap my head around how to do it. Any suggestions?

" with escapesign

@Mr.Irrelevant that won't work inside a raw string.

You can use a so-called multi-line string (it doesn't have to be actually multi-line). You wrap the string content in triple quotes ''' or """, and inside the string you should be able to use a single ' or " without any issue.
